# Snowflake - Schedule a Script.sql- with multiple instructions (insert, delete, create view, create table, etc)

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, schedule

I come from making a script.sql to fill and create tables to a database. ( 10000 lines of code)

The script is big, since I have to apply some logic to be able to fill some tables, all the instructions are like this ( *BY EXEMPLE*):

That is, my script is made up of many instructions, when I run it in the WorkSheet, everything works perfectly.

My question is, how can I fit all my script logic into one task? Any architecture advice before I start thinking about CRAZY options?

*BY EXEMPLE*

--- 1 statement
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.AFFAIRES.CLIENT .....;

--- 2 statement
DROP TABLE TEST.AFF.CLIENT;

--- 3 statement
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST.AFF.PROVIDER .........;

--- 100 statements  etc....

Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write them into a stored procedure to run them all from a single task. If you don't want to write your own stored procedure, I wrote one that will read SQL statements written to a table and run them one at a time. That way all you have to do is store the statements in a table with a numbered order column to tell it the sequence. It includes simple variable substitutions.

I'm planning to move this to Snowflake Labs (it did not exist yet when I wrote this), and you can grab it here now if you're interested or just want to see how it works to try something similar:

https://github.com/GregPavlik/snowflake_script_runner

Comment: HI Greg!!! 
Thank you very much for your script !!! It is very useful to me ... and it will serve me a lot.
However I have a question, why is it not possible in a single line to write several SQL statements? Is it a scope problem in javaScript?
When I try to place a second statement on the same line (within the column 'SQL_COMMAND' several statements followed by the ';' as in the worksheet), the stored procedure shows the message :
ERROR:Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.

Comment: Hi @Ser, the Snowflake API for JavaScript does not support multi-statement transactions. You'll need to run them one at a time using the "snowflake" object in JavaScript that exposes the API. You can use "begin" and "commit" with the Snowflake API to make them one transaction, but I haven't tested that in the stored procedure I referenced. You could try adding a begin and commit rows to a script in the table and I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Greg is correct: A stored procedure can run all these statements in a single task.

As an alternative you could use Snowflake's stream and tasks, where you define a task with a single SQL statement, but then other tasks are automatically executed once this root task completes. This can start a chain like what you describe:

> root_task -> create_task -> drop_task -> view_task

For example, 3 connected tasks:

```sql
create or replace task mytask_minute
  warehouse = test_small
  schedule = '1 MINUTE'
  when SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('just_timestamps_stream')
as
delete from just_timestamps_stream_table;

create or replace task mytask_minute_child1
  warehouse = test_small
  after mytask_minute
as
insert into just_timestamps values(current_timestamp, 'child1');

create or replace task mytask_minute_child2
  warehouse = test_small
  after mytask_minute
as
insert into just_timestamps values(current_timestamp, 'child2');
```

Full example here:

https://github.com/fhoffa/snowflake_snippets/blob/main/stream_and_tasks/minimal.sql